# React implement routes from array programitically

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a file called routes.js there I import components and create a routes array.

**routes.js**

```
import Country from '../src/components/country/Country';
import Countries from '../src/components/country/CountriesList';

import User from '../src/components/user/User';
import UsersList from '../src/components/user/UsersList';

export const routes = [
  {
    name: 'USER',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Create',
        path: '/user-create',
        component: User,
        // isHidden: true,
      },

      {
        name: 'Update',
        path: '/update-user',
        isHidden: true,
        component: User,
      },
      {
        name: 'View',
        path: '/users',
        component: UsersList,
        // isHidden: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'COUNTRY',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Create',
        path: '/country',
        component: Country,
      },
      {
        name: 'View',
        path: '/countries',
        component: Countries,
      },
    ],
  },
  
  
    ],
  },
  
];
```

Then, I want to import that routes array and render routes programmatically.
I did this.

```
{routes.map(
                {children}=>
                  children.forEach({component,path} => <Route component={component} exact path={path}/>)
                
              )}
```

**This gives me a syntax error.**
I think this is because I am trying to render with a ForEach loop.
How do I fix this syntax problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function which will return an array of components which React can render.

```
{routes.flatMap(items => items.children).map(({ component, path }) => <Route component={component} exact path={path}/>)}
```

You were also missing some parens `()` around the curly braces which caused the Syntax error.

E.g. in the following part, you are trying to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object containing the `children` property. However, you will need to wrap the destructing syntax with parens if you use this in an arrow functions.

```
{routes.map({children} =>
```